# Rails - Looping but setting a MAX?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following:

```
@books.each do |book|
... stuff
end
```

I'm curious to learn. How can I update the above to do something like loop through @books but not more than 6 times, MAX/ceiling of 6?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to take a slice of the Array and iterate over that:

```
@books[0,6].each do |book|
  # ...
end
```

The alternative is to keep the Array intact and bail out of the loop when you're done:

```
@books.each_with_index do |book, i|
  break if (i == 6)

  # ...
end
```

Comment: what if books doesn't have 6 items? for the first exapmle? trying to understand what that's doing?

Comment: That's a simple Array slice and will take a maximum of 6 items. If the array is only of size 3 then you will get only 3. The first parameter is the index of where to start, which in your case is 0, but you can adjust this to take the 7th through 12th using `[6,6]`

Comment: When in doubt, toy around in `irb`! `%w[ a b c d e f g h ][0,3]` yields `[ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]`

Answer (score 1):

```
@books.each_with_index do |book, i|
  if i >= 6
    break
  end
  ... stuff
end
```

Comment: Spinning through what could be a very large list is inefficient. The `break` technique described in Jacob Relkin's answer is a better approach.

Comment: heh, caught me before I changed it.

Answer (score 1):

```
@books.each_with_index do |book, i|
   break if i > 5
   #stuff...
end
```

Comment: I see you fixed your arguments, but you've got the classic "Off By One" error. `i` goes from 0..5, not 0..6 if you want only 6 elements.